# How to loop a program and increase the date by 1 on each next loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

I want to change the following program to print all(infinite) dates from a given date specified by `def increase_by_one(self):` but I don't know where to begin with. :( And I want to start from a specific starting date, no need to start from 01-01-0001

```
    def date(self):
        var_date = (datetime.datetime.now()+timedelta(%s)).strftime('%Y%m%d') % self.increase_by_one()
        return var_date
    def print(self):
        x= self.date()
        print(x)
```

Comment: what is the unit of increase, you mean increase by one day each time?

Comment: @YoussefNajeh yes, increment of one day on each loop

Comment: you should build another function that transforms the date into days so you can easy increment

Answer (score 2):

If you want an infinite stream of dates, you could use a generator.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def gen_dates(start_date):
    one_day = timedelta(days=1)
    while True:
        yield start_date
        start_date += one_day
```

You can use it like this:

```
In [3]: g = gen_dates(datetime.now())

In [4]: next(g)
Out[4]: datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 19, 15, 3, 21, 102090)

In [5]: next(g)
Out[5]: datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 20, 15, 3, 21, 102090)

...
```